# Vue - can't see the git interfase to solve conflicts

Tags: vue.js, merge, conflict

As say in title, vscodium, doesn't showme the colors interfase on code, when I have conflicts in merge, when working in Vue.js (in React.js it works normaly).

[image: Instead I see the conflicts like this.]

```
    <<<<<<< HEAD
  {
    title: 'Ajustes de Perfil',
    icon: settingsOutline,
    to: '/settings/profile',
    enabled: true,
  },
=======
  // {
  //   title: 'Ayuda (FAQ)',
  //   icon: helpCircleOutline,
  //   to: '/faq',
  //   enabled: true,
  // },
>>>>>>> 2c12cce44b0f9ce3ea754042d62849ff867ab621
```

- And meaning, this is the interface I expect to see.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxNOc.png)

Comment: This comes maybe from your theme or the fact that there are some `//` there, not sure.

Comment: If this is not what you expect to see, then what is? Please be more descriptive.

Comment: I have to say that I experienced just the same today. So it may be a regression of some sort. Will be worth to give the issues a look, there is probably somebody with the same issue.

Comment: @kissu > The // represents Comments, it is a correct part of code, and does not generates the Git Interface error, same error occurs in every conflict.

Comment: @paddotk >What I expect to see, is the git interface with two blocks of code in differ colors, usualy green and blue, with some options above that allows you to take Current Changes, or Incoming Changes, and other Options.

Comment: What you describe is a feature of your editor, which transforms `<<<<<<< HEAD ===== >>>>> xxxxx` into colored/clickable blocks. This has nothing to do with Vue nor javascript. Perhaps you need to install or update a plugin.